# Two users in same group and the group is owner of concrete directory

Tags: linux, permissions, xampp

I have two users on my Linux box:

- John: an admin
- Jane: a normal user.

I added them both into group called `xampp_users`. How can I allow both users to have read/write/execute permissions for directory `/opt/lampp`? I changed the owner and group of `/opt/lampp` to `xampp_users`, but it did not work.

Comment: please post the result of `ls -ld /opt/lampp` and `grep xampp_users /etc/group`

Answer (score 0):

If `ls -l /opt/lampp` displays the correct group, you probably have not applied the correct permissions for that directory. Use this command to fix that issue:

```
chmod g+rwx /opt/lampp
```

If you need to apply the permissions to the files in the directory too (probably yes), use `-R` to recursively apply commands `chmod`, `chown`, or `chgrp`.

If you want the new files created in this directory to be owned by the `xampp_user` group and not the main group of each user, use:

```
chmod g+s /opt/lampp
```

I you have not already, you may need to change the umask of the users to allow `rwx` on the group. Run `man umask` to learn how to apply the umask you want.